# RTK Query. Can't set the type of query result

Tags: typescript, authentication, rtk-query

I'm trying to create a re-authorization using RTK Query according to the [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-re-authorization-by-extending-fetchbasequery)

Backend response object:

```
{
  user: IUser,
  accessToken: string
}
```

In the code below TypeScript error: **Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type '{}'**
(line marked #)

What should I do?

```
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/api/',
  credentials: 'include',
  prepareHeaders: headers => {
    headers.set(
      'authorization',
      `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('bearer-token')}`
    )
    return headers
  },
})

const baseQueryWithReauth: BaseQueryFn<
  string | FetchArgs,
  unknown,
  FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
  if (result.error && result.error.status === 401) {
    // try to get a new token
    const refreshResult = await baseQuery('auth/refresh', api, extraOptions)
    if (refreshResult.data) {
      // store the new token
      console.log('refreshResult.data:', refreshResult.data)

      if (refreshResult.data.hasOwnProperty('accessToken')) {
#        localStorage.setItem('bearer-token', refreshResult.data.accessToken)
      }
      // retry the initial query
      result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
    } else {
      // api.dispatch(())
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a type assertion doing `as`, or actually test the result using something like `zod`. At this point you are getting data back from the web. From TypeScript's perspective, that could be *anything* - you as developer have to tell it what it should assume.

Comment: Thanx @phry! I'm added 
`const data = refreshResult.data as { user: IUser, accessToken: string }`